# CSS onhover Popup

Tags: css

I have created CSS onHover popup as given [here](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/FuaRJ/1/). but problem is, User should be able to click the Register [link](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/FuaRJ/1/) in the example. here, Popup disappears as I move the mouse aware form the link. 
Can anyone tell how it could be achieved ?

HTML:

```
<div class="how  f-left">
<h7><a href="how-it-works">How does this work?</a></h7>
<div class="how-works bubble-outer">
<div class="navigation-up-arrow"></div>
<div class="body">
<h4>How It Works</h4>
<ol class="bubble-inner">
<li>Tell Us What's Wrong </li>
    <li class="">  <a href="#">Register</a> to Get Quotes from Local Shopshere  </li>
<li class=" bold-txt ">Call Shop / Get Vehicle Serviced </li>
<li>Get Cash Back </li>
</ol>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Below CSS is used for onHover PopUp:

```
.how h7:hover + .how-works {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it display on hovering the parent (`.how`), not just its preceding sibling. Hovering the parent happens when you are hovering any of its descendants (the link, `.how-works`, any of the children of `.how-works`).

To do this, change:

```
.how h7:hover + .how-works {
    display: block;
}
```

to:

```
.how:hover .how-works {
    display: block;
}
```

### [*DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/FuaRJ/3/)

---

Also, if you want to make it work for touchscreens (no `hover` there), you could adjust a bit your HTML. Change

```
<h7><a href="how-it-works">How does this work?</a></h7>
```

to

```
<a class="how-it-works" href="#" tabindex="1"><h7>How does this work?</h7></a>
```

and add this to the CSS as well:

```
.how-it-works:focus + .how-works {
    display: block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/FuaRJ/8/)

Comment: +1 great ! Can you please explain me how this happened ? So, I will accept this answer ?

Comment: @Umesh Well, I don't mean to interfer, but it works because when you specify `.how h7:hover` you're only including the link in the `:hover` detection. `.how:hover` includes the link + the space around it + the "popup box".

Comment: +1 but @Ana also the `position: relative; top: 0px;` css properties would be required to `.how .how-works.bubble-outer{ ... }` to align `.bubble-outer` right under the `h7` element (there is 1 or 2 pxs between theese 2 elements that can make you loose the `:hover` state for `.how`) [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/FuaRJ/6/)

Comment: Hi Ana, Abody97, Alexander V.B. This is okay ! but I need to get this work in Internet Explorer also. Any idea ? why it doesn't work ?

Comment: @Umesh It does work if you decrease the top offset for `.how-works` just a tiny bit: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/bbXja/). To make the positioning more "guaranteed", refer to AlexanderVB's comment.

Comment: @Umesh Accept Ana's answer, it resolved your issue. Positioning is another, irrelevant issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.how-works:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Modified version of your demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/bbQCL/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FuaRJ/6/).

Put

```
.how:hover .how-works {
    display: block;
}
```

instead of

```
.how h7:hover + .how-works {
    display: block;
}
```

and add `position: relative; top: 0px;` css properties to `.how .how-works.bubble-outer{ ... }`